# how to get value name in object user with v-for in nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

this my array

```
 [
  {
    created_at: "2020-09-24T19:30:14.000Z",
    user: {
         id: "4ce79a30-fed4-11ea-9746-fb38f847bf3c",
         name: "Dicky Mochammad Sidiek",
    },
  }
]
```

I want to retrieve the data name in the user object, can anyone give me an example of how to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <p v-for=" (user ,i) in users" :key="i"> {{user.user.name}}</p>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            users: [{
                created_at: "2020-09-24T19:30:14.000Z",
                user: {
                    id: "4ce79a30-fed4-11ea-9746-fb38f847bf3c",
                    name: "Dicky Mochammad Sidiek",
                },
            }]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```